# xcode -- conditional compilation based on build configuration

Tags: xcode, build, preprocessor

I'd like to compile differently based on which build configuration I'm using. Something like

```
#ifdef DEBUG
 // debug code goes here
#endif
```

I know I can do this by defining preprocessor macros for each build configuration. But I'm wondering if there's already something built-in I can ues. Is there?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've always used and it's very clean. It also comes up when you search your code, which is nice, since settings, etc...may not.